# Typing for nested objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to retrieve data from an specific leave in an object with a combination of 2 keys. I am having trouble correctly typing the key(s) for accessing the nested objects.

Given this object structure

```
const movies = {
  "Shawshank Redemption": {
    rating: 9,
    versions: {
      "Directors Cut": {
        length: 111,
      },
      Cinema: {
        length: 113,
      },
    },
  },
  "The Dark Knight": {
    release: 2008,
    versions: {
      Standard: {
        rating: 9,
        length: 113,
      },
    },
  },
};
type MovieKey = keyof typeof movies;
```

How can I correctly type the VersionKey in this method? Is it even possible?

```
function getMovieVersion(movie: MovieKey, version: VersionKey)
```

Comment: (Aside: you don't need "in tsc" in the title; TypeScript is implied by the tag, and tsc is just the compiler program anyway which is a bit distracting.) You can use *generics* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOXMzN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah thank you. Yes that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `getMovieVersion()` to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function in which `movie`'s type is a generic type parameter `K` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `MovieKey`.

Then you can [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `typeof movies` with `K` as the key type, and then into the result with `"versions"` as the key type, and then finally use `keyof` the result to get `version`.  That is, if `movie` is of type `K`, then `version` is of type `keyof (typeof movies)[K]["versions"]`:

```
declare function getMovieVersion<K extends MovieKey>(
    movie: K,
    version: keyof (typeof movies)[K]["versions"]
): void;
```

You can verify that this works as expected:

```
getMovieVersion("Shawshank Redemption", "Cinema"); // okay
getMovieVersion("The Dark Knight", "Standard"); // okay
getMovieVersion("Shawshank Redemption", "Standard"); // error!
// -----------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"Standard"' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type '"Cinema" | "Directors Cut"'
```

---

If you also need to know specifically the literal type of `version` so that you can get the specific type of the output, you can use two generic type parameters as follows:

```
declare function getMovieVersion<
    MK extends MovieKey,
    VK extends keyof (typeof movies)[MK]["versions"]
>(
    movie: MK,
    version: VK
): (typeof movies)[MK]["versions"][VK];

getMovieVersion("Shawshank Redemption", "Cinema").rating; // error
getMovieVersion("The Dark Knight", "Standard").rating; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtiAbgSwKYRgXhgbwFAyEwBEAygBYCGA7hFWANYwBKqAJqnAA5TLjEAuXASKiATpV5gA5kICcAGhGjCiVGIh9IQ-Cr0kAIsjGpgUEBpgBhAK5RBw-U5gAbVDKjkhARl9LnRAC+-gHWyGCclDrKoYRuHl4wvgDMIQHBMaIZWWkkACrkqDAGlGJMANJgyNLk9tFOJm6UEKhCAEwADB0AHLmiahpaEPWhpFCUYGylbCOxhBJSsjCKmaHx0p4+3qmretn6+4QZgQDceHhQAJ5cRQCySGjlqJdYMAzPIABmMFc3X-APdBnDjAFylIqfGxgMxaGDSVBQe4oVAANXUmnAAB5yjBUAAPKDuNgYJGPZ4APgAFDEEMihOVcgMMWAhO9Lv9Kb9UP9aWgIABKADa5QAuoLiEyhsQRXh+UJECBkGwznh4YjAWjBuBKWQqLR6ExWBxuLx+AoSFZwpFiPyTjAAPT2mAgBiUS6qhGk1HorQ6gpFEplGCVaq1YjmsjjSbTG12x3O13utVezXMnUUGh0CaG9icHhacMkMYTKZiNixh1O9RiCwAQjw8YAtM2W622+2Ox3yTAAH59-sDhtOgCCYmkNjg7lg-y5MAA5JGSzG5zBkBgwCBYM1NNIwJQAEZuGBDn4gGBcUqUSeEsTO76zheWiJwSjEGAAH0MxlM5kstnsc7nHge6ThAF7AEUADyt66EQIJgiYMCQtCppgHCnoaj6WK7DAtw4vihKTCSgJPJcfRECi+EEkSGBshyXI8oCAqCnhYoSlhkDSjEVI4byrS4QyOGSuAQiUTEcowJy1zct8fHMax4rCZxYqUSKKqiMmmFamA6Z6lmjAsLmJoFhGT7WvyAB0CzhNIcZVmINZiDEmnIqmvrEP6xSlBUVQ1PYEbFtGZY2lZkg2XZCZukBgRAA)

Comment: The goal is to return a `movieVersion` that combines all attributes from `movie` with its `version`. Typing works well when calling the method, but when I try to use the `versionKey` to get the `version` (e.g. `movies[movie]["versions"][version]` it tells me that Type '...' cannot be used to cannot be used to index type 'string  | …'. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Presumably that’s [ms/TS#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181)